how to install mysql 8.0.28 on ubuntu
I want to install mysql mysql:8.0.28-oracle on oracle. when I run mysql on my terminal I get this,
Command 'mysql' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0     # version 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, or
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.3  # version 1:10.3.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

I suppose client-core is slightly higher version of my intended version, which is being 8.0.28
I checked  this link  it shows that I can download the package for a specific version, yet I want to ask if this is possible:
If I run
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0.28

with full version in the package name, will I get mysql:8.0.28-oracle installed ?

please don't ask yes/no questions; there is no merit in answering it. Why not execute it and see for yourself? it can do what you want or error out. and if it does install and not do what you want purge it. it is not like installing software will burn down your system :)
